# Converted PC power supply producing too much voltage

Tags: power-supply, power, conversion, pc

I have converted two ATX PC power supplies to 12V bench power.  They have worked flawlessly for the past 5 years.  Suddenly, both are providing 17V+.  What could be causing this?  I have a 10ohm resister connected between the 5V and ground.  Should I put this on the 12V as well?  The 5V rail produces the most current as they are both old power supplies.

Comment: Are you sure that resistor is still good? A 10 Ohm resistor on 5V dissipates 2.5 Watts, that's much more than a standard resistor can handle.

Comment: Have you measured them in the past and found 12V at no-load?

Comment: Just tried a new resistor....no change.  Also measured the voltage in the past no load and it was around 14v

Comment: If your multimeter measures 17V on both supplies, change multimeter batteries.

Comment: what do the other outputs measure?